# Unable to input values fully in a text field using send keys. Only partial values entered and no error shown

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

Unable to input values fully in a textbox field using send keys. Only partial values entered and no error shown.

Attempted sending keys with a wait.
Attempted sending keys slowly.

[Edit] - This is the entire script as requested in the comments below

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import 

Keysdriver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.volunteers.ae/register.aspx")


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='topnav_btnLangShift']").click()

driver.find_element(By.ID,'body_txtFName').send_keys("RADHIKA")

driver.find_element(By.ID,'body_txtLName').send_keys("PORANKI")

driver.find_element_by_id("body_txtEmail").send_keys("radhika.po@gmail.com")
element=driver.find_element_by_id("body_ddGender")
dropdown=Select(element)dropdown.select_by_value("Female")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_body_txtDOB_dateInput").send_keys("08/04/1986")
element=driver.find_element_by_id("body_ddNationality")
dropdown=Select(element)
dropdown.select_by_value("India")
element=driver.find_element_by_id("body_ddCountryOfResidence")
dropdown=Select(element)
dropdown.select_by_value("+971")
element=driver.find_element_by_id("body_ddEmirate")
dropdown=Select(element)
dropdown.select_by_value("DUBAI")
time.sleep(10)

element=driver.find_element_by_id("body_ddCity")

dropdown=Select(element)

dropdown.select_by_value("DUBAI CITY")

def ClickAndSlowType(element, text):
    element.click()
    sleep(1) # let scripts run
    for t in list(text):
        print(t)
        element.send_keys(t)
        sleep (0.1)

mobile = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_body_txtEtisalat']")))
mobile.click()
mobile.send_keys("68862632")
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you post the HTML or a link to page that you're trying with.

Comment: dear i am using below link "https://www.volunteers.ae/register.aspx"

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail - what machine are you running this on?  - running everything you have as-is works for me. i get then full phone number populate.  I'll have a look at what else springs to mind but an obvious difference is our machines....

Comment: i am using laptop with windows 7 as OS

Comment: @Paul, i tried it in different forms but i can't get your issue to  appear.  I'm going to post some more code with some more debug inside my answer - when you try it can you please describe exactly what you see happen with this field?  (does it type at all, does it only do one character, etc.. - i can't see it so i need you to tell me so i can get a feel for what to try next

Comment: @paul keep me posted with how you get on

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem when you run your script?

I enhanced your script with a wait action and it works great:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.volunteers.ae/register.aspx')

mobile = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_body_txtEtisalat']")))
mobile.click()
mobile.send_keys("68862632")
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

There does seem to be some scripting at work in the page. Evertyime you click and type it resents the field. However, the above code still seems to work.

If there's a problem, let me know what's happening (with any relevant errors that occur) and i'll look again.

---

[Update!]

Based on the comments below, try typing with a delay.
Add this import:

```
from time import sleep
```

Add this function:

```
def ClickAndSlowType(element, text):
    element.click()
    sleep(1) # let scripts run
    for t in list(text):
        print(t)
        element.send_keys(t)
        sleep (0.1)
```

Run this:

```
mobile = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_body_txtEtisalat']")))
ClickAndSlowType(mobile, "68862632")
```

I can't recreate your issue but this also works for me so worth a try. It just types a bit slower in case of the funky in-page script issues.

Let me know how it goes.

If you can update your question with your entire i code i might be able to recreate and provide a tried and tested answer.  (no one likes "it worked for me")

---

As it works locally but not on @Paul 's machine : we need to debug it . Try this at the end of the script and please tell exactly what you see happen to the field and what the output from the prints on the console:

```py
def WaitForDocumentReadyState():
    print("Ready State Before: " + driver.execute_script('return document.readyState'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')


def ClickAndSlowType(element, text):
    element.click()
    WaitForDocumentReadyState()
    sleep(1) # let scripts run
    for t in list(text):
        element.send_keys(t)
        WaitForDocumentReadyState()
        sleep (0.5)
    sleep(1) # let scripts run
    WaitForDocumentReadyState()    


mobile = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_body_txtEtisalat']")))
#mobile.click()## REMOVED
#mobile.send_keys("68862632") ## REMOVED
ClickAndSlowType(mobile, "68862632")  ## using the function
```

Comment: i tried with your script but still it entered number till "056-_______" and stopped. No error shown.

Comment: Is your script doing anything else? or are you just running the steps provided?  - there is the funky script stuff going on in browser so it could be that

Comment: I added you a plan b approach to type slower in the asnwer. HAve a got and let me know. If it doesn't work i need to know what you're doing to recreate the issue (please update your question with all your code for this page so i have the full context) :-)

Comment: i tried the plan b also but still same issue. i am just trying to fill the form by providing inputs for the fields exist in the page.

Comment: The fields you're doing, in the order you're doing them, at the speed you're doing them is the context i need to recreate the issue.  CAn you please share this extra info in your question?  - edit the post, create a new code block and add all your code so i can see everything that's happening